# Cleaning (NOT deleting) cells with a row shift up

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2013

[To clear patients from a table I use this simple line of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBdRw.jpg)

[image]

```
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
```

Every time I do this I loose rows at the bottom of the table since it's deleting rows, not clearing values.

Is there any other way to shift the remaining rows up (without affecting my table) after clearing the green ones?

"PAID" is just a simple button for color change within selection.

Comment: my table
http://postimg.org/image/3sga0fqdp/

Comment: There is no simple line of code for this. If you just `.Clear` your selection, you will end up with empty rows. You can, however, cut and paste the remaining rows (Try the macro recorder).

Comment: Why don't you want to delete the rows?  It looks like your table is a pre-formatted range in your sheet and that deleting rows will reduce the number of rows.  Is that the problem?

Comment: Asume line 5 is empty and you want to shift up then `Range("C5:G99") = Range("C6:G100")`

Comment: I don't want to delete rows because my table gets shorter at the bottom every time there's up-shift.
Verzweifler:  Selection can be different every time, so how would I code the "remaining part"?

Answer (score 1):

This code will remove the contents from the selected row, and move every row under that selected row up.
If it encounters an empty row, it will simply stop running.

For clearance purposes you should not select the B column, but only the C to G column.

```
Sub delete_line()

For i = 1 To 100000
    Selection.ClearContents
    Selection = Selection.Offset(1, 0).Value
    Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select
    If IsEmpty(Selection.Cells(1, 1).Value) = True Then Exit For
Next i

End Sub
```

Haven't tested it with more than one row selections.

Edit:
It won't work if you select more than one row.

Comment: `(Selection.Cells(1, 1).Value)`
What does that mean? First Cell in selection?

Comment: Yes, it's a stop feature so it won't loop through every row in the entire document, but stop at the last unused row.
It simply checks if the row below the row we just moved up, is empty or has data, and if it has data it will continue the process of moving the rows up.

If the question was what Cells(1,1) is refering to, it will be the top-left cell of the selected cells.